# What is the sampling distribution of the standard error of regression coefficients to get an accurate histogram?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, sampling, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to fit the pdf on the variance of regression coefficients. I understand how to plot the regression coefficient estimates, the noncentral t-distribution, but I am always off for when I try to plot the standard error (var) of the estimate. I understand that it should follow a chi square distribution, but I don't understand how it should.

```
B=.25
n=25
reps=100000
res = matrix(0,reps,4)
for (i in 1:reps){
  x = rnorm(n)
  y = B*x+sqrt(1-B^2)*rnorm(n)
  res[i,] = summary(lm(y~x))$coefficients[2,]
}
colMeans(res)

par(mfcol=c(1,3))
h1=hist(res[,1],plot=FALSE)
plot(h1,freq=FALSE)
x=seq(-.5,1,by=.01)
y=dnorm(x,mean=B,sd=sqrt((1-.25^2)/(n-2)))
lines(x,y)

h2=hist(res[,2]^2*(n-2)*(1-.25^2)*n,plot=FALSE,breaks=21)
plot(h2,freq=FALSE)
x=seq(0,100,by=.001)
y=dchisq(x,df=(n-2))
lines(x,y)

h3=hist(res[,3],plot=FALSE,breaks=21)
plot(h3,freq=FALSE)
x=seq(-4,8,by=.01)
y=dt(x,ncp = B * sqrt(n-2)/(sqrt((1-.25^2))),df=n-1)
lines(x,y)
```

Here are the results :

```
colMeans(res)
[1] 0.2495763 0.2016862 1.2933058 0.3106487
```

[image]

The second distribution seem off in the second panel. I am not sure what I did wrong. It is normal? Thanks you for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what does `res[,2]^2*(n-2)*(1-.25^2)*n` mean.

1. In general, with the usual assumptions, $\dfrac{(n-2)MSE}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-2}$.
2. In the simple regression, $Var(\hat{\beta}_1)=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$.
3. In R, the estimated standard error of the coefficient is $\hat{Var}(\hat{\beta}_1)=\dfrac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$ where $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is MSE.

Using these facts,
$$\left(\hat{sd}(\hat{\beta}_1)\right)^2\times (n-2) \sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})^2 / \sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-2}$$

So, try this code:

```
B=.25
n=25
reps=100000
res = matrix(0,reps,4)
ssx = c()
for (i in 1:reps){
  x = rnorm(n)
  y = B*x+sqrt(1-B^2)*rnorm(n)
  reg = summary(lm(y~x))
  res[i,] = c(reg$coefficients[2,])
  ssx[i] = sum((x-mean(x))^2)
}
h2=hist(res[,2]^2*(n-2)*ssx/(1-B^2),plot=FALSE,breaks=50)
plot(h2,freq=FALSE)
x=seq(0,100,by=.01)
y=dchisq(x,df=(n-2))
lines(x,y)
```

Then, you should get
[image]

Comment: Thanks @stati ! What I may have missed is that $\sum (x-\bar{x})^2$ is random. I thought I could use $n-1$ (simply $n$ in my OP) as an estimator. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @POC $\sum(x-\bar{x})^2$ is not random actually and we do not estimate it. Only $\epsilon$ (and therefore, $Y$ and $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$) has randomness. So, in your code, `res[,2]^2*(n-2)*(1-.25^2)*n`, `n` should be `sxx` and `*(1-.25^2)` should be `/(1-.25^2)` (I think this was just a typo.)

Comment: one more question, what would it be, if there was more IV? Thank you!

Comment: @POC What is IV? If you mean instrumental variables (or just independent variables), it is useful to use a matrix. In that case, $Var(\mathbb{\beta})=(X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2$ and $Var(\hat{\beta}_1)$ will be the corresponding diagonal element (usually the second one) of that variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: IV is for independent variable. Thanks, it is what I thought.